# Tcl string escape

Tags: string, tcl

Heyhoo,

now i need to compare a String like "[INTENSITY]" to $line. ATM i want to do it like

```
if { [string compare "[INTENSITY]" $line] == 0 } { }
```

but i think there is a problem with the "[" and the "]". But how could i escape it ?
I could not find a good book or a really good website online.

Next Question is i created an array like

```
set data [split $file_data "\n"]
```

why i coulnd say `array stat $data` ???

Hope you could help me again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the first item, use `{}` as string delimiters to prevent command substitution (which is what happens with [] in a double-quoted string)

```
if { [string compare {[INTENSITY]} $line] == 0 } { }
```

On the second item, `split` creates a list, not an array.  Index into it with `lindex`:

```
set data [split $file_data "\n"]
puts [lindex $data 1]
```

The best website for tcl info is the Tcler's Wiki at http://wiki.tcl.tk/

Comment: +1: Alternatively, put backslashes in front of the square brackets.